# reportlab ValueError: Invalid color value 'initial'

Tags: python, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

ReportLab/xhtml2pdf have worked perfectly until now when it crashes at this style bit in HTML:

```
<p style="border-style: initial; border-color: initial; border-image: initial; 
 font-family: Ubuntu-R; font-size: small; border-width: 0px; padding: 0px; 
 margin: 0px;">Done:</p>
```

with this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/lib/colors.py",
line 850, in __call__
    raise ValueError('Invalid color value %r' % arg)
ValueError: Invalid color value 'initial'
```

I use it typically like this:

```
     pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), 
result, encoding='UTF-8', link_callback=fetch_resources)
```

Is there a way to overcome this other than patching it's original code?

Comment: oddly enough same version on my windows box doesn't crash and generates pdf. so: Windows7x64 - all good, fedora - no luck.

Comment: I patched the reportLab color thing and if defaults are null just return defaults for black - this temporary fixes the issue but I'm looking for better options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `border-style: initial` value is not correct. See [the code](https://bitbucket.org/sdolan/xhtml2pdf/src/fc4087589fc0/sx/w3c/cssSpecial.py#cl-95) as a reference for supported `border-style` values:

- none
- hidden
- dotted
- dashed
- solid
- double
- groove
- ridge
- inset
- outset

Comment: ok it's not correct, however, say if you browser crashed when coming across this style you would not expect to work it this way, would you. I'm pretty much in the same place with this - I don't manage the styling but need my reports done :)

Comment: Browsers were designed to handle low-quality/incorrect pages. Python modules are not (as it makes bugs harder to handle).

Comment: it looks like I can set default colors and styles to this whilst generating reports. can't figure how yet.